# ANDROID: Get n rows from SQLite Database using Swipe to Refresh

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, swiperefreshlayout

I'm new to android programming. I'm still practicing and making this simple app.
I want to get 2 rows per refresh from SQLite Database and display on a listview.

But what I am getting now is the first 2 rows again and again.

My database already has data with 6 rows.

What I don't know is how to pass offset to the Database Operation and how to get the next 2 rows.

Thank you so much for your time. I hope someone can help me.

Pls see my code below:

**DisplayItem.java**

```
public class DisplayItem extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

private String TAG = DisplayItem.class.getSimpleName();
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

private ListView list_view;
private SwipeAdapter adapter;
private List<Item> itemList;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_item);

    list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDisplay);

    itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new SwipeAdapter(this, itemList);
    list_view.setAdapter(adapter);

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fetchItems();
            }
    });

}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    fetchItems();
}

public void fetchItems() {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

    DatabaseOperations db_op_sw = new DatabaseOperations(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = db_op_sw.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor display_cursor_swipe = db_op_sw.displaySwipeInfo(db);

    String name;
    int id, qty, price;
    int offSet = 0;

    if (display_cursor_swipe.moveToFirst()) {

        do {
            id = display_cursor_swipe.getInt(display_cursor_swipe.getColumnIndex(ItemContract.ItemEntry.ID));
            name = display_cursor_swipe.getString(display_cursor_swipe.getColumnIndex(ItemContract.ItemEntry.NAME));
            qty = display_cursor_swipe.getInt(display_cursor_swipe.getColumnIndex(ItemContract.ItemEntry.QTY));
            price = display_cursor_swipe.getInt(display_cursor_swipe.getColumnIndex(ItemContract.ItemEntry.PRICE));
            Item item = new Item(id, name, qty, price);
            itemList.add(item);
            offSet = offSet + id;
        } while (display_cursor_swipe.moveToNext());

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}

}
```

**DatabaseOperations.java**

```
public class DatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DB_NAME = "item_info.db";
private static final String CREATE_QUERY = "create table " + ItemContract.ItemEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                                            "(" + ItemContract.ItemEntry.ID + " text,"
                                            + ItemContract.ItemEntry.NAME + " text,"
                                            + ItemContract.ItemEntry.QTY + " integer,"
                                            + ItemContract.ItemEntry.PRICE + " integer);";

public DatabaseOperations(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    Log.d("Database Operations", "Database successfully created");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
    Log.d("Database Operations", "Table successfully created");
}

 public Cursor displaySwipeInfo(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String[] projections = {ItemContract.ItemEntry.ID, ItemContract.ItemEntry.NAME,
            ItemContract.ItemEntry.QTY, ItemContract.ItemEntry.PRICE};

    Cursor display_cursor_swipe = db.query(ItemContract.ItemEntry.TABLE_NAME, projections, null, null, null, null, null, null, "2");
    Log.d("Database Operations", "Viewed row");
    return display_cursor_swipe;
}

 @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track :)

So the 2 is the limit which is set on the query. You can also set offset,query in that place. You can keep a counter for refresh count and use it to create the offset.

```
 Cursor display_cursor_swipe = db.query(ItemContract.ItemEntry.TABLE_NAME, projections, null, null, null, null, null, null, offset+",2"); //offset,limit
```

or

```
 Cursor display_cursor_swipe = db.query(ItemContract.ItemEntry.TABLE_NAME, projections, null, null, null, null, null, null, "limit "+2+",offset "+offset);// limit 2 offset 3
```

or

```
you could resort to db.rawQuery(SQLSTATEMENT); // SQLSTATEMENT is select statement in string which has LIMIT,OFFSET set on it.
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your reply :)

I still don't know how to pass the offset from DisplayItem.java to DatabaseOperation.java

Comment: Maybe first take total count of entries in db during onCreate. Send that value to your fetchItems. For each refresh increment a counter which keeps in mind total number of entries and sets the offset based on counter. Pass that offset value to displaySwipeInfo method as argument and use it within your query

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much again for the reply. I'm really having a hard time because I don't know how to pass the offset value to the displaySwipeInfo method. Can you help me with the code? thank you so much!

Comment: public Cursor displaySwipeInfo(SQLiteDatabase db, int offset) { ... } and then in fetchItems() { ..calculated offset.. Cursor display_cursor_swipe = db_op_sw.displaySwipeInfo(db,offset); .. }

Comment: Hi Richie, thanks again for your reply :) my app is working now!
But I still have a little problem. The loop doesn't stop on the last row. 
I already got the total count of entries in db put it on itemCount variable.

Where should I put itemCount on fetchItems()?

Comment: put a check to see if calculated offset is more than total count. If it is reset offset to 0

Comment: Hi Richie,
Thank you so much! My app is working now :)

I've learned a lot! Thank you!!! :D